# Using Time::Piece with Apache::Log::Parser

Tags: apache, perl, parsing, cpan

I am using [Apache::Log::Parser](http://p3rl.org/Apache::Log::Parser) to parse Apache log files.

I extracted the date from log file using the following code.

```
my $parser = Apache::Log::Parser->new(fast=>1);
my $log = $parser->parse($data);
$t = $log->{date};
```

Now,I tried to use [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) to parse dates, but I'm unable to do it.

```
print "$t->day_of_month";
```

But, it's not working. How to use Time::Piece to parse date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call methods on objects inside of string interpolation. It will probably output something like this:

```
Sat Feb 18 12:44:47 2017->day_of_month
```

Remove the double quotes `""` to call the method.

```
print $t->day_of_month;
```

Now the output is:

```
18
```

Note that you need to create a Time::Piece object with `localtime` or `gmtime` if you have an epoch value in your log, or using `strptime` if the date is some kind of timestamp.

Comment: Removed the double quotes and it throws an error 
`Can't call method "day_of_month" without a package or object reference`

Comment: @Pradeep read the last part of my answer. You need to create an object first. Just dropping Time::Piece in doesn't magically convert some value to a date object.

Comment: Tried to create a new `Time::Piece Object` ,`Time::Piece->strptime($log->{date}, "%Y");`
but keeps throwing error
`Error parsing time at C:/xampp/perl/lib/Time/Piece.pm line 469`

Comment: @Pradeep read the error message, and look at your date string. `%Y` is only the year as four digits, like _2017_. You need the _full_ timestamp.

Comment: Format of Date : `31/Jul/1999` My Format String : `%dd/%mmm/%YYYY`.what changes do I need to make to this format string?

Comment: Did you even read the documentation @Pradeep? The Time::Piece docs links to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html which clearly explains how it works. `%d/%b/%Y` should match `31/Jul/1999`.